# inverse of an infinite banded, upper-triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

There's probably a trick to the following which I'm not seeing.

For a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of all nonzero scalars (in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), set
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&-a_1&0&0&0&\cdots
\\
0&a_2&-a_2&0&0&\cdots
\\
0&0&a_3&-a_3&0&\cdots
\\0&0&0&a_4&-a_4&\cdots
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This matrix is invertible, but is there an easy way to actually find $A^{-1}$?

Thanks!

EDIT:  So, apparently the inverse is
$$
A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&\cdots
\\0&1&1&1&\cdots
\\0&0&1&1&\cdots
\\0&0&0&1&\cdots
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1^{-1}&0&0&\cdots
\\0&a_2^{-1}&0&\cdots
\\0&0&a_3^{-1}&\cdots
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1^{-1}&a_2^{-1}&a_3^{-1}&a_4^{-1}&\cdots
\\0&a_2^{-1}&a_3^{-1}&a_4^{-1}&\cdots
\\0&0&a_3^{-1}&a_4^{-1}&\cdots
\\0&0&0&a_4^{-1}&\cdots
\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Yes, It is invertible. Note that it is upper triangular so that the eigen values are diagonal entries. Here you have determinant and I think you can find adjoint of this matrix.

Comment: You matrix has the form $\Lambda(I - \eta)$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with value $a_i$ at $i^{th}$ diagonal matrix entry and $\eta$ is a matrix with $1$ at the super subdiagonal and $0$ else where. As long as all $a_i \ne 0$, you matrix has a formal inverse  of the form $(I + \eta + \eta^2 + \cdots)\Lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: @achille hui perfect solution, once more, that you should give as an answer. A remark: one can explicitate $I+\eta+\eta^2+\cdots=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1 \cdots\\ 0&1&1&1 \cdots\\0&0&1&1 \cdots\\0&0&0&1 \cdots\\ \cdots&&&\cdots \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @achillehui Awesome thank you !